# Ask questions about using an open API

Tags: support, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Which Q&A site is best place to ask a question regarding the following issue:

- I send a request to an open API as I think according the specs
- I get an unexpected error (a field is not accepted)

In the question I would provide the specs example and HTTP transcript of the request.

Comment: Does the API have no support mechanism itself? It's usually best to start there, rather than Stack at all.

Comment: @RobertLongson do you mean creating a support request at the hosting organization?

Comment: Yes, that's mostly where you would expect support. Or alternatively ask the organisation that wrote the spec.

Comment: If you provide an actual [MCVE / MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then it *may* be reasonable to ask on Stack Overflow. Frankly, it's really going to depend on the issue you're actually having. There will be some things which just *can't* be answered by anyone other than Customer Support for the company that provides the API. There will be other things which can be answered by users here. Note that a lot of these types of questions end up being a typo in the parameters that are passed to the API, so check for such issues carefully.